# Finding an Argument Pattern for Function Defintion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, argument-patterns

I'm defining what's called a fractional integral in Mathematica, which acts on a list of functions that depend on $x$:

```
integral[α_, g_[x_][[i_]], x_] := Integrate[(x-t)^(α-1) g[t][[i]], {t, 0, x}]
```

with some assumptions that say the $x$ in the bounds is nonzero.

What it does is it takes a function $f(x)$, kept in a list, changes the variable to $t$, and integrates it along with a power law, evaluating the bounds at $0$ and $x$. The problem is that sometimes I have to input a different form of a function, for example,

```
integral[α, (g[x][[i]])^3, x].
```

Mathematica doesn't recognize it as a viable function and just returns it back without doing anything.

I need to find a robust pattern that would take any function of $x$ and change it to a function of $t$ inside the integral. Changing, in the definition,

```
g_[x_][[i_]] -> g_[x_]
```

doesn't help.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: When you say the functions are kept in a list, what do you mean exactly? Can you provide an example list (suitably short and simple) that shows what form the functions are in? Depending on the answer to this question, I would suggest something much simpler than specifying a pattern for the function. In addition, why put the `Part` specification in the `Pattern` when you can just `Map` `integral` over the list of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility that does away with having to do any complicated pattern-matching. Suppose you have a list of expressions to be integrated, given by

```
lst = {x^2, (x + 1)^2, x};
```

Define a function

```
Clear@integral
integral[a_, func_, var_] := Integrate[(var - t)^(a - 1) Evaluate[func /. var -> t], {t, 0, var}]
```

In this case, the symbol that goes into `var` must match the independent variable in your list of expressions. Then, if you want to integrate the functions in `lst`, just `Map` `integral` over the list:

```
integral[2, #, x] & /@ lst
(* {x^4/12, x^2/2 + x^3/3 + x^4/12, x^3/6} *)
```

The key is to use the replacement in

```
Evaluate[func /. var -> t]
```

to change variables inside the `Integrate` call.

---

Alternatively, if you need to specify different variables, then we can define an alternative version:

```
Clear@integral
integral[a_, func_, inVar_, x_] := Integrate[(x - t)^(a - 1) Evaluate[func /. inVar -> t], {t, 0, x}]
integral[a_, func_, var_] := integral[a, func, var, var]
```

Now suppose the list was

```
lst = {x^2, (y + 1)^2, z};
```

Then, we can do either

```
MapThread[integral[2, #1, #2] &, {lst, {x, y, z}}]
(* {x^4/12, y^2/2 + y^3/3 + y^4/12, z^3/6} *)
```

or, if you want the outputs to have all the same output variable,

```
MapThread[integral[2, #1, #2, x] &, {lst, {x, y, z}}]
(* {x^4/12, x^2/2 + x^3/3 + x^4/12, x^3/6} *)
```